# escaping special character in groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to run my command in background.And I am trying this in jenkins pipeline
This is my command

sh "./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone start  \&"

But when I run this command & gets single quote because of which the command fails.
OUTPUT :  ./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone start '&'

Can anyone suggest how I should escape the & in groovy so I just get & without single quote.

Answer (score 3):

This won't work that easily, first because `&` is a command for job control in the interactive shell, and also because of how process trees work in Linux.

To make a long story short, if you need to start a command in background, you should use [daemonize](http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/):

```
sh label: "starting selenium in the background",
    script: "/usr/local/bin/daemonize ./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone start"
```

Comment: @ MaratC When I tried the above script after installing daemonize 
I am getting the following error The 'path' parameter must be an absolute path name. 
Script : /usr/local/bin/daemonize  ./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone start

Comment: As indicated by message, you should convert the path `./node_modules/...` to absolute path starting with `/`, e.g. `/users/jenkins/workspace/project/node_modules/...`.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is no special character to Groovy.  It is for the shell.  So if you *dont* want to start this command in the background but want to pass `&` as an argument to your script there, you have to use `\\&` inside `"`-strings. And if you want to start the script in the background, then just use `&`.