# Shell script execution in Jenkins pipeline is stuck

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Through Jenkins pipeline, I have to start license server on linux machine, hence I have written following method -

```
def startLicenseServer() {

            sh '''
                 cd "/home/oracle/License"
                 sh ./startLicServer.sh start
                 '''
}
```

It is executed and license server is started but other statements after it in pipeline are not. Could you please help me to resolve how this process is executed in background and still other following pipeline statements are executed?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60308605/2047614

Answer (score 0):

The `start` command is executing in the foreground. Groovy `sh` command completes only if the script returns the control. Can you try executing it in the background (`sh ./startLicServer.sh start &`) and see?

Comment: This won't work, as 1) `&` is a command to interactive `bash` and 2) once `sh` returns, it's killed and all of its child processes are killed with it. We use `daemonize` to start things in background.